# Realm Object Server. Offline object status

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

For a offline realm db(sync to a realm server), is there a way to know:
 - How many object are waiting to be sync
 - The date of the last sync for a specific object

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know the synchronization state of a specific `Object`, but the `SyncSession` class implements a mechanism to [register for notification blocks](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#progress-notifications) outlining the overall progress of any current sync operations.

```
let session = SyncUser.current!.session(for: realmURL)!
let token = session.addProgressNotification(for: .download,
                                            mode: .reportIndefinitely) { progress in
  if progress.isTransferComplete {
    hideActivityIndicator()
  } else {
    showActivityIndicator()
  }
}

// Much later...
token?.stop()
```

If you have a specific use-case that could benefit by knowing the sync state of an exact `Object`, please feel free to open an [issue on the Realm Cocoa GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues) outlining its details.